# Arduino check equality of uint8_int

Tags: arduino, uint8t, arduino-c++

I'm trying to check the equailty of  `uint8_t` type when I press a button on my Arduino shield. I understand the type is an unsigned integer, but the code never enters the if statement even though I get the print statement `"Button pressed: 0"` Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <MFShield.h>

MFShield mfs ;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mfs.onKeyPress( [](uint8_t button){
    if (button == 0 || button == 0x00 || button == '0')
    {
      Serial.println("working");
    }
    Serial.println("Button pressed: " + String(button)); 
  });
}

void loop() {
  mfs.loop();
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `button` in your code?

Comment: `button == 0` and `button == 0x00` does the same thing so you can get rid of one of them.

Comment: are you sure that it prints Button pressed: 0??  the callback should not be called if you don't press a key (button == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments

`button == 0` and `button == 0x00` are the same thing. So one can be omitted.
`button == '0'` doesn't make sense as `'0'` is `48`. This will never be true in your program.

From what I see in the source code of the MFShield librarie's [source code](https://github.com/DireCat/MFShield/blob/d790f1c606265148939895b1dbd39c46aa49a5c2/MFShield.cpp#L91) the described behaviour should not be possible.

```
// Keys polling
    if (onKeyPress_func != NULL && time - t_buttons >= MFS_BUTTONS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MS)
    {
        t_buttons = time;
        uint8_t key_mask = 0;
        for (uint8_t i=0; i < 3; i++)
            key_mask |= (!digitalRead(KEY_PIN[i]) << i);

        if (key_mask != key_mask_pre)
        {
            if (key_mask != 0)
            {
                key_mask_pre = key_mask;
                onKeyPress_func (ffs(key_mask));
            }
            else
                key_mask_pre = 0;
        }
    }
```

The code checks all 3 buttons and sets a bit in key_mask for each button pressed.

The callback function `onKeyPress_func` you provided is only called when `key_mask` is unequal 0 and when the key state has changed since last checked.

So using this code you should never get the print "Button pressed: 0" as you claim. Your `button` cannot become `0`. It is either 
For the same reason you'll never enter your if statement.